# Is the set of monotone functions $f:[a,b] \to [0,1]$ compact in $L^2([a,b])$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, compactness, monotone-functions

Is the set of equivalent classes of monotone functions $f:[a,b] \to [0,1]$ compact in $L^2([a,b])$?

Comment: what do you mean with "the set has compact support"?

Comment: Can  you tell us why it is closed?

Comment: For clarity you should say equivalence classes of monotone functions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy.  for closeness : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1570240/795522

Comment: The basic space here is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Let $f_n$ be a sequence of such functions.  By the [Helly selection theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397931/hellys-selection-theorem), there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ converging pointwise to some $f$, which is clearly again monotone.  And by dominated convergence this subsequence also converges in $L^2$.